# Need to push the key and value inside associative Array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I need to push the more key and its value inside the array. If I use below code first key pair replaced by 2nd one.

For your Reference:

**Code Used:**

```
foreach ($projectData['projectsections'] as $key => $name) {
$projectData['projectsections'][$key] = ['name' => $name];
$projectData['projectsections'][$key]= ['id' => '1'];
}
```

**Current result:**

```
'projectsections' => [
    (int) 0 => [
        'id' => '1'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'id' => '1'
    ]
],
```

**Expected:**

```
'projectsections' => [
    (int) 0 => [
        'name' => 'test1',
        'id' => '1'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'name' => 'test2',
        'id' => '1'
    ]
],
```

How can I build this array in PHP?? Any one help??

Comment: You're overwriting your array with your third line, just combine lines 2 and 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either add the entire array:

```
$projectData['projectsections'][$key] = ['name' => $name, 'id' => '1'];
```

Or add with the key name:

```
$projectData['projectsections'][$key]['name'] = $name;
$projectData['projectsections'][$key]['id'] = '1';
```

Answer (score 5):

With

```
$projectData['projectsections'][$key] = ['name' => $name];
$projectData['projectsections'][$key]= ['id' => '1'];
```

you are setting a new Array for that `$key`. This is not what you want.

This should work:

```
$projectData['projectsections'][$key] = ['name' => $name, 'id' => '1'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Change it to :

```
foreach ($projectData['projectsections'] as $key => $name) {
  $projectData['projectsections'][$key]['name'] = $name;
  $projectData['projectsections'][$key]['id'] = '1';
}
```